# get minimum and maxiumum time for a particular date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've separate columns for start( timestamp ) and end( timestamp) and i need to get the earliest starttime and last endtime for each date.

```
   number               start                 end  test      time
0       1 2020-02-01 06:27:38 2020-02-01 08:29:42     1  02:02:04
1       1 2020-02-01 08:41:03 2020-02-01 11:05:30     2  02:24:27
2       1 2020-02-01 11:20:22 2020-02-01 13:03:49     1  01:43:27
3       1 2020-02-01 13:38:18 2020-02-01 16:04:31     2  02:26:13
4       1 2020-02-01 16:26:46 2020-02-01 17:42:49     1  01:16:03
5       1 2020-02-02 10:11:00 2020-02-02 12:11:00     1  02:00:00
```

I want the output for each date as : Date Min Max

I'm fairly new to Pandas and most of the solutions i've across is finding the min and max datetime from column. While what i want to do is min and max datetime for each date, where the timestamps are spread over two columns

expected output (ignore the date and time formats please)

```
date        min     max
1/2/2020    6:27    17:42
2/2/2020    10:11   12:11
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael : added expected output.

Comment: are the start and end irrelevant here? can min be from the `end` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to start by creating a `date` column and later performing `groupby` with `date`.

```
df['date'] = df['start'].dt.date
df['start_hm'] = df['start'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df['end_hm'] = df['end'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')

output = df.groupby('date').agg(min = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'start_hm',aggfunc='min'),
                                max = pd.NamedAgg(column='end_hm',aggfunc='max'))
```

Output:

```
              min    max
date                    
2020-02-01  06:27  17:42
2020-02-02  10:11  12:11
```